# Error with 8-bit Quantization in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have been experimenting with the new [8-bit quantization feature](https://petewarden.com/2016/05/03/how-to-quantize-neural-networks-with-tensorflow/) available in TensorFlow. I could run the example given in the blog post (quantization of googlenet) without any issue and it works fine for me !!!

Now, I would like to apply the same for a simpler network. So I used a pre-trained network for CIFAR-10 (which is trained on Caffe), extracted its parameters, created corresponding graph in tensorflow, initialized the weights with this pre-trained weights and finally saved it as a GraphDef object. See this [**IPython Notebook**](https://gist.github.com/abidrahmank/ba75c0e305b6d859117263af74c21599) for full procedure.

Now I applied the 8-bit quantization with the tensorflow script as mentioned in the Pete Warden's blog:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/quantization/tools/quantize_graph --input=cifar.pb  --output=qcifar.pb --mode=eightbit --bitdepth=8 --output_node_names="ArgMax"
```

Now I wanted to run the classification on this quantized network. So I loaded the new `qcifar.pb` to a tensorflow session and passed the image (the same way I passed it to original version). Full code can be found in this **[IPython Notebook.](https://gist.github.com/abidrahmank/d715ae0526b31dc6967ed44e36c713db)**

But as you can see at the end, I am getting following error:

**`NotFoundError: Op type not registered 'QuantizeV2'`**

Can anybody suggest what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the quantized ops and kernels are in contrib, you'll need to explicitly load them in your python script. There's an example of that in [the quantize_graph.py script itself](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/quantization/tools/quantize_graph.py#L41):

`from tensorflow.contrib.quantization import load_quantized_ops_so
from tensorflow.contrib.quantization.kernels import load_quantized_kernels_so`

This is something that we should update the documentation to mention!

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting an importError. I am using tensorflow 0.9 using pip installation. Is there anything else to do during installation to import these modules ?

Comment: Although I couldn't import as you do, I did a small work around as I have explained here : **http://stackoverflow.com/a/38495999/1134940**. Now everything works fine. Thank you. I would really love to see more details on documentation, also I want to try out other quantization methods.

Comment: Which files should I include to make it work using the C interface from iOS?